# How do I add a User Defined Function to Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a simple stored procedure that returns a Description and a Name when you give it a ID.  I need to enable this inline in multiple Excel Sheets.  Something like `=ItemLookup('12345')` that would then return the aforementioned info.

I have not done a lot with Excel programming and am simply wondering what my options are for tackling this.  Is this a VBA thing or should this be an external DLL that I COM register?  Both felt like overkill but then I realized I had no idea if they were.  I really wanted to use VSTO for this but it sounds like that is not possible for Cell level UDF's without having to modifiy each Workbook with some VBA.

Comment: Is this stored procedure in a DB or is it actually a VBA function? How are your workbooks distributed now?

Comment: It's in a DB.  As to your second question I'm not sure what you mean...all of the workbooks exist in a directory that the Users will use as a 'base' to create a new workbook....make sense?

Comment: I read "deploy" as you have workbooks on many users computers and you need to add this function to them. But you have a folder of `xltx` files and you need to add your function to them?

Comment: Sorry, I was being "thick".  I need to delpoy this to a group of User's so that they can use this function in any Excel book they open or create.  I found the following article which seems to be A way to go about this. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eric_carter/archive/2004/12/01/273127.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to add UDF functions to Excel is with [Excel-DNA](http://excel-dna.net) (which is a free, open-source library I develop), and any of the .NET languages - VB.NET, C# and F# are all fine.

To get started you make a new 'Class Library' project in Visual Studio (any edition), install the 'Excel-DNA' package from the NuGet package manager, and add your code:

```
Public Module MyDataAccessFunctions
    <ExcelFunction(Description:="Gets the Item from the database")>
    Public Function ItemLookup(code As String) As String
        ' Here you have to do some work to get the data
        Return "Hello " & code
    End Function
End Module
```

Pressing F5 builds and starts Excel, and you're done - try putting `=ItemLookup("Paladin")` into a cell.

The resulting add-in is a single .xll file, which you can copy and use on any machine that has .NET without any installation or admin permissions. It works with old Excel versions too.

The best place for support (including absolute beginners' questions) is the [Excel-DNA Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/exceldna).

Comment: That's too funny.  I came back here to close this question because I had "stumbled" on ExcelDNA through NuGet and it's quite amazing and what do you know!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Excel to create a VBA UDF pretty easily, just hit alt+f8, right click your project in the project hierarchy on the left of the screen, and click add module.

Here is a quick Hello World function you can just paste into the module, then click play (or alt+f8 from worksheets)

```
sub test()
msgbox "helloworld"
end sub
```

If it was me, I would probably just create a list of the file paths that need to be searched. Then create a VBA macro that opens them in excel, searches them for the key, and returns other information from the row the key was found on.

- You can open files with the 'Application.Open' method, simply pass in
  the file path as an argument. 'Application.Open' returns a workbook
  object.
- Each workbook will have several worksheets, you can access them
  through the workbook's 'Worksheet' property
- Getting each used cell in a workbook can be done via looping through the 'UsedRange'
  property in each worksheet
- Get the value of a cell for comparison from the cell's 'value' property
- Cells also have a 'row' property so you can find other items on the same row

If you're used to VBA you could get this running in less than an hour. But since you're just starting out it'll probably take a 3+ hours since you'll have more research/debugging